# очистить гит репозиторий от удалённых файлов

Tags: git

Исторически возник большой репозиторий с несколькими десятками слабо связанных проектов. 
Начитался что разделить можно просто склонировав репозиторий и удалив ненужные проекты. Склонировал, удалил. В проекте осталась только нужная папка, всё удалённое закомиттил, но папка .git разрослась больше полугигабайта. При том что сам проект мегабайт 50.

Можно ли как-то почистить репозиторий от удалённых файлов и их истории?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для большого количества файлов или небольшого репозитория можно попробовать `git filter-branch` (см ответ от Arhad).

Для большого количества файлов, массовых чисток, или удаления случайно вкоммитанных паролей стоит использовать [утилиту `BFG Repo-Cleaner`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Она позволяет массово переписывать историю, и делает это *очень быстро*. На порядок быстрее `git filter-branch`. `git filter-branch` приходится вызывать для каждого файла, и он заново пересчитывает историю для каждого файла. Если файлов больше двух, это занимает вечность. Repo-Cleaner делает все за один проход.

Из базовых примеров:

Удаления файлов по маске:

```
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Удаление папки целиком

```
bfg --delete-folders somefolder --delete-files somefolder
```

Удаление больших файлов

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M  my-repo.git
```

BFG по умолчанию не удаляет блобы в текущей ветке (`HEAD`), так что она идеально подходит для массовых чисток и переписывания истории без риска запороть последний коммит.

В качестве гайда можно воспользоваться справкой GitHub по чистке репозиториев:

- [Removing files from a repository's history](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/)
- [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы удалить все упоминания конкретного файла из истории репозитория необходимо воспользоваться командой `git filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --ignore-unmatch <путь>'
```

где `<путь>` — это путь до удаляемого файла относительно текущей папки (не корня репозитория!).

Учтите, что эта команда занимается переписыванием истории. То есть она берёт старое дерево и переносит его в новую копию, коммит за коммитом, после чего переназначает текущую указатель-ветку. Поэтому она работает очень медленно (около секунды на перенос одного коммита).

Затем надо удалить пустые коммиты, образовавшиеся на месте тех, в которых были изменения только удалённых файлов:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@"' HEAD
```

После переписывания истории надо убрать все оставшиеся хвосты, чтобы как можно скорее уменьшить размер репозитория:

1. Рвём все связи старых (исходных) коммитов с `git reflog`, чтобы сделать их недостижимыми:

   ```
   git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0
   ```
2. Удаляем все недостижимые объекты (и упаковываем оставшиеся):

   ```
   git gc --prune=all --force
   ```

Так как переписывание истории порождает новое дерево, которое не может быть наложено поверх одноимённой ветви любой другой копии репозитория, то ближайший `git push` придётся однократно сделать с ключом `--force`. То же самое касается и всех тех, кто будет выполнять `git pull`.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас был репозиторий гит на полгигабайта и вы сделали коммит, в котором грохнули 99% этого репозитория - то давайте определимся, вам то, что было ранее уже не пригодится никогда и можно этот архив грохнуть, либо вам вам это нужно?

Если нужно - то создайте новый репозиторий из оставшихся файлов, а в старый будете посматривать, если понадобится что-то глянуть.

Если не нужно - схлопывайте историю коммитов оставив только последний (`git rebase -i HEAD~100`), а потом делайте `git gc` и `git push --force`